# Knockout validation addClass to parent of validation element

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

How can I use my class in knockout validations on parent of element?
My code is here

```
<li>
    <label for="">Residence:</label>         
    <select data-bind="options: passengerDocs.countries(),
                       optionsText: 'Key', optionsCaption: 'ChooseCountry',
                       value: Passport().CountryOfResidenceName">
    </select>
</li>
```

I added this code to knockout.validation.debug.js

```
ko.bindingHandlers['validationElement'] = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var obsv = valueAccessor(),
            config = utils.getConfigOptions(element),
            val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(obsv),
            msg = null,
            isModified = false,
            isValid = false;

        var valueIsValid = valueAccessor().isValid();
        if (!valueIsValid) {
            $(element).parent().addClass('passengerDetails_error');
        } else {
            $(element).parent().removeClass('passengerDetails_error');
        }.........
```

but it doesn't add the class passengerDetails_error to li
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to change the built in `validationElement` or create a bunch of new computed properties... you can just use the `validationElement` directly on the `li` with the correct `validationOptions` http://jsfiddle.net/DAjuY/

Comment: @nemesv Whereas your comment is a useful one in demonstrating the way to neatly implement the validation method, how does this address Guy Z's question with regard to applying the validation class to the parent element as he clearly requests?  Your fiddle example would simply apply the class to the li item and not the ul item unless I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: @CarlEdwards although my comment shows a not as generic solution as the OP wanted but still it could be a good compromise and the OP explicitly said that he wants the validation on the `li` element: "but it doesnt add the class passengerDetails_error to **li** Any ideas?"

Comment: @nemesv Apologies. Now I've re-read the op I can see that I made a false assumption that he wanted the class applied to the <ul> element and it's clear he doesn't. My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right path.  I dont think you need to change the knockout validation code, instead you can create a new binding handler for your case:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.parentValidationElement = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var cssClass = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor);
        var obs = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor()).value;

        var decorateElement = obs.isModified() && !obs.isValid();
        if (decorateElement) {
            $(element).parent().addClass(cssClass);
        } else {
            $(element).parent().removeClass(cssClass);
        }
    }
}
```

used like:

```
<li>
    <label for="">Residence:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Residence, parentValidationElement: 'passengerDetails_error'" />
</li>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39kQj/